# how can run and edit locally this Angular website with VS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am new in Angular things and need to run and edit a angular website. The files I got from the web server (windows Server 2012).

This is the web server directory
[image]
Then tried to remote edit the website with Webmatrix, but this did not work because there is no proper debugging.

Now want to run and edit the website locally. 
The database i could setup locally. She is the base for the (asp.net mvc) webservice the website runs with.

For edit and debugging the webservice and website structure i want use Visual Studio, but i dont know how to bring in all the files and make them run.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use Visual Studio to manage the project? Or simply because it's the text editing software you're accustomed to using? Here is a good starting point either way: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/node-js-vs.aspx Actually perhaps you aren't even using node.js?

Comment: When you say "make them run", I can only assume you mean that you want to access the files in a web browser? In any case, VS has it's own built in IIS Express (or IIS) or you could use something else (node, etc.). BUT the main point I have taken away is that you need a debugger. If that is the case, there is no need for VS -- you could simply use the Developer Tools of your browser (example for chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). And then just access the files from the file system or host the files using a simple server -- I recommend https://github.com/indexzero/http-server

Comment: I want to edit and debug the website in Visual Studio because i know VS from coding c#.

Comment: Based only on your screenshot, and unless I missed it, where would the server side/C# code be? If you know what type of Project, you could try, FILE -> NEW -> PROJECT FROM EXISTING CODE and see if that works...Hth..

Comment: The Angular web site has java script only and consumes data from a web service on the same server. The web service is written in .Net C#. The web site is java script/Angular stuff.

I dont know how to make this work together on a local mashine. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the new VS Code editor. as this is all client side.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/code-vs.aspx
and if you create a website in IIS, and copy the code into the WWWROOT directory you will be good to go.

Comment: Its a client website and need a modification. Make a own website brings not the needed result. I need to modify some business logic and structure.